# Static content is not getting loaded in JSP page from spring boot application

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am creating a SpringBoot web application that while render a .jsp page with some static entities like images.
I have tried adding the static files in each and every folder from **META_INF** to **static** but getting the 404 error at console and the images are not displayed.

---

[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJFBl.png)

---

The HTML code is as follows:

```html
<img src="image/nia-logo.png">
```

---

The Spring Boot Application class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class FeedbackApplication  implements WebMvcConfigurer{  

@Autowired
private Environment environment;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(FeedbackApplication.class, args);
}



@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {     
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/resources/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/resources/static/");
    }

}
```

}

---

Please help me and mention where am I making the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the addResourceHandlers Configuration, it defines that any calls starting with `/resources/**` is treated as resource files.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/resources/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

So what you need to do is change the src url to `<img src="/resources/image/nia-logo.png">`

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)

Comment: I am new this architecture, I help me with the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: After changing the src url, did you check it is implemented on dev server as well? you can pull up a developer mode if you are using chrome or firefox to see if the src url is changed.

Comment: I am using Chrome and in "Network" tab, the image is 404 not found and the URL it is picking is: **localhost:8080/resources/image/nia-logo.png**

Comment: Okay you should change `addResourceLocations` to `"classpath:/static/"` See if this works!

Comment: In Spring `classpath` is pointing to `src/main/resources` so if you set resource location as `classpath:/resources/` then what it does is to find resource folder under the `src/main/resources` which is redundant and wrong at your case. You put static files under `src/main/resources/static` so the location is simply `classpath:/static/` :)  By the way I'll change my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also you need to add `/resources/` at the beginning of your static src url because in the configuration you tell the resourceHandler that any calls with `/resources` at the beginning need to be treated as static by adding resourceHandler.